# Other's edit is joined with mine

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

I edited this post and added a missing double quotes `"` in the code.

In the same time, somebody else edited it and removed some other lines.

When checking revision, the other's edit is mapped to my account.

Revision https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43152339/revisions

Comment: You made an edit that removed stuff directly related to the question as well as adding the missing quotation mark while they were also editing the question to simply add the missing quotation mark, which means it added the text back in that you removed because they did not remove the same text. Why did you remove that text?

Comment: @TinyGiant read the question carefully. _I edited this post and added a missing double quotes " in the code.

In the same time, somebody else edited it and removed some other lines._

Comment: Are you saying that literally the only thing you did was add a single `"`, and the other deletions were not you?

Comment: @EdCottrell yes. Exactly. When I finished edit(inline edit), then it showed _An edit has been made to this post. click to reload_ When I reloaded, the edit is applied but towards my account

Comment: That would be exceptionally weird. How did you make the edit? On a computer, on a phone using a browser, or in a mobile app?

Comment: windows 10 Chrome

Comment: This is pretty common side-effect of editing a post while the grace period is still in effect.

Comment: @EdCottrell: no it isn't. The edit was made *during the grace period*, so the OP added text, that was missing from the version that Sagar edited. So his revision was accepted and that was effectively removing the text again. This happens to me too from time to time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting; I've never seen that before. I'm with OP: seems very confusing to show it that way.

Comment: @EdCottrell: well, the diffs are just generated based on the actual contents. Not much can be done other than pay attention to the 'post has been edited' notifications. It's not as if it is hard to put the text back in. *Or*, just not edit so soon after a post is created.

Comment: @EdCottrell: the alternative is to insert a revision ID that is unique even to grace-period revisions into the edit form, then block accepting the edit if there was a change. That has downsides too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters normally if I am editing a post and someone else already edited it, then it shows `can't submit edit. person x edited the body. reload the edit.` Why it did't show this time?

Comment: @SagarV: no, you get that message only if your change is *not substantive enough*; the message states your change is not different enough and is not accepted.

Comment: @SagarV: in other words, as long as your edit is different enough from the previously accepted revision, it'll be accepted. Regardless of when that other revision was made (before or after you started editing).

Comment: @MartijnPieters one more doubt. _during the grace period_ what is the duration of the grace period?

Comment: @SagarV: 5 minutes. Any follow-up edit by the same editor is folded into the revision without any further trace for that duration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Something like an SHA-256 hash of the Markdown source, as it was before the edit, would make a perfectly good "unique revision ID" for detecting edit conflicts. And it wouldn't even need to be stored anywhere on the server side, since it can always be recalculated from the text itself.

Comment: this behavior is quite confusing for not-so-experienced user and can even lead to edit rejections that sound like it would be bad if the editor gets a few of them (`This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you started editing, the post was missing some text still. However, the OP was **also** editing the post, during the grace period, and added that text before you submitted your edit.

You then submitted your edit, which was based on the revision without the text, and that effectively removed it again.

The diff shows what changed, not what you edited. And because the OP made the edit in the grace period, there is no actual audit trail for this, other than the time stamps (the post was created at 03:04:25 UTC, you edited at 03:05:19 UTC, well within the 5 minute grace period).