# I edited a question and OP's edit was combined with mine

Tags: bug, edits

I just edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971691/non-static-function-assigning-in-constructor) question. All I did was add indentation to two lines, and backticks to two identifier names. The edit history says I also added comments to the code. The OP's edit was combined with my own.

Having read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252051/i-did-not-do-all-those-edits) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346303/others-edit-is-joined-with-mine), it sounds like a side effect of editing a question that is still in the grace period. But, this is backwards. I didn't accidentally rollback an edit, a second edit was attributed to me. I haven't found any other meta questions about this.

Is this also by design?

Comment: The OP edited **after you started editing**, and so your edit was based on a now-outdated revision. Your edit *reversed* their later change, which *removed* text making it look like you added the text. A race condition.

Comment: In other words, this is *exactly the same thing* as those other cases.